# How come this connect 4 does not work? (Python Widget)

Tags: python

First of all, I am stuck on how to add the winner in. Second of all Instead of the X or O going over the block, they replace the block instead. Can someone help me please and tell me if they are any more flaws?

````
def draw_board():
   '''draw a board to play Connect Four'''
   for c in range(7):
       print(c, end=' ')
   print()
   for r in range(6):
       for c in range(7):
           print(board[r][c] + ' ', end='')
       print()    
playerList = []
player1 = input("Player X, please enter your name: ")
player2 = input("Player O, please enter your name: ")
playerList.append(player1)
playerList.append(player2)

print("Alright guys, let's get started! Here is your board: ")
draw_board()

import random

def play_c4():
   '''plays a game of Connect Four'''
   numPlayers = len(playerList)
   currentPlayer = random.randrange(numPlayers)

   winner = False
   while not winner:
       move1 = int(input('\n' + playerList[currentPlayer] + ' , what column do you want to play in? '))
       if playerList[currentPlayer] == player1:
           board[5][move1] = "X"
       if playerList[currentPlayer] == player2:
           board[5][move1] = "O"
       
       draw_board()

       currentPlayer = (currentPlayer+1) % numPlayers

play_c4()```
````

Comment: What happens when it is run?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading (this article is a little rude, which I don’t mean to be, but it is also informative): [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)